# Как сравнить два временных ряда

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, анализ

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сравнить два временных ряда?

У меня есть две таблицы, в каждой из которых есть DF['Месяц Год'] и DF['Выручка'].
Построены два временных ряда для двух таблиц. Нужно проанализировать поведение клиентов. Т.е. определить, что эти два ряда ведут себя одинаково? Есть ли уже готовый метод в библиотеках, который помогает это сделать?

---

Я разделила на кластер: по дате и выручке! И посмотрела на сколько себя репрезентативно ведут два кластера. Сопоставимы ли две выборки.

Comment: Вы можете привести небольшие примеры данных для сравнения?

Comment: Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: Вопрос, на который вы должны ответить в первую очередь: Что понимается под словами "ведут себя одинаково". Ответов существует много. И в зависимости от того, как именно вы трактуете "одинаковость" можно будет вам рекомендовать тот-или иной путь решения задачи. Ждем.